# What is the name of this popover class?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I cannot find the name of the class for this '`popover`'. Apple uses it a lot in their applications.

I've searched for `popover`, `NSAlert`, custom hidden/visible views, and many more.

What is it called?

[image]

Comment: Looks like UIAlertController

Comment: indeed, of style ActionSheet

Comment: In Xcode 6 UIActionShit And Now Xcode 7 is The UIAlertController Added "UIActionShit" Also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `UIAlertController`. Before ios7 it is know as `UIActionSheet`

A `UIAlertController` object displays an alert message to the user. This class replaces the UIActionSheet and UIAlertView classes for displaying alerts.

```
    @IBAction func showActionSheetTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
  //Create the AlertController
  let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Swiftly Now! Choose an option!", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

  //Create and add the Cancel action
  let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
    //Just dismiss the action sheet
  }
  actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
    //Create and add first option action
  let takePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Picture", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    //Code for launching the camera goes here
    }
  actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)
  //Create and add a second option action
  let choosePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose From Camera Roll", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    //Code for picking from camera roll goes here
    }
  actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)

  //Present the AlertController
  self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

May be it will help you.